# Run regression with many variables and try every combination

Tags: r, regression

I remember that in R there is a function similar to

```
lm(Y~ ., data=data)
```

However, this function tries every combination of X variables, and then shows the best 5 models based on adjusted R-squared. Could you help to find this function (or package)

Comment: Run `help("lm)`. The call in the question regresses `Y` on all other variables present in `data`, not on every combination of X variables, and then shows the best 5 models.

Comment: Look at the ExhaustiveSearch, abess, bestglm and leaps packages.